# Switch background and foreground plot in matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Code:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot
import pandas

fig, axs = pyplot.subplots(figsize=(width, 5))
axs.plot(data_1, index_1,color=color)
ax2 = axs.twinx()
dataFrame = pandas.DataFrame(data={k:data}, index=index)
dataFrame.plot.bar(ax=ax2,rot=15, title=f"Timeseries analysis for {city}: {d} ({k})",alpha=foreground_opacity)

pyplot.close()
```

There are multiple Y Axis in the graph.

**The data plotted on the left Y-Axis in always shows in background**

**And The data plotted on the right Y-Axis in always always shows in background**

[image: Here is the picture]

I want to switch the background to foreground and vice versa

Comment: Have you tried using [`zorder`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/misc/zorder_demo.html) when plotting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can draw a bar chart first and then a line chart. Are there any restrictions on the order in which you can draw them?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = [10,20,30,40,50]
index = [0,1,2,3,4]
data_1 = [25,15,35,45,55]

foreground_opacity = 1.0

dataFrame = pd.DataFrame({'data':data}, index=index)

# fig, ax2 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))
axs = dataFrame.plot.bar(rot=15, alpha=foreground_opacity, figsize=(10, 5))
ax = axs.twinx()
ax.plot(index, data_1, color='r', lw=3)

# pyplot.close()
plt.show()
```

[image]